# Javascript | If sentence

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know javascript but I would like to do something that I dont know how. In this code these lines repeat constantly:

```
    if (jsonLength==0)
{

    html+='<div class="desc"> <div class="thumb"> <img class="img-circle" src="" width="35px" height="35px" align=""> </div> <div class="details"><p style="padding-left: 10px;"><a  href="#"></a><br/>Sê o primeiro a escrever no chat!</p></div> </div>';
}
```

How do I stop them from repeating? Full code here

```
var lastTimeID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSend').click(function(){
        sendChatText();
        $('#chatInput').val("");
    });
    startChat();
});

function startChat(){
    setInterval(function(){ getChatText(); }, 700);

}

function getChatText(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID="+lastTimeID
    }).done(function( data )
    {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
        var html = ''; 

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.results[i];
            html += '<div class="desc"> <div class="thumb"> <img class="img-circle" src="' + result.picture +'" width="35px" height="35px" align=""> </div> <div class="details"><p style="padding-left: 10px;"><a  href="#">' + result.user_name +'</a><br/>'+result.chattext+ '</p></div> </div>';
            lastTimeID = result.id;
        }
        if (jsonLength==0)
{

    html+='<div class="desc"> <div class="thumb"> <img class="img-circle" src="" width="35px" height="35px" align=""> </div> <div class="details"><p style="padding-left: 10px;"><a  href="#"></a><br/>Sê o primeiro a escrever no chat!</p></div> </div>';
}
        $('#view_ajax').append(html);

    });
}

function sendChatText(){
    var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
    if(chatInput != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
        });
    }
}
```

It has some php parts, but I dont think that they are usefull for this question

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this right below your `var html = '';`

```
if (jsonLength==0)
{
    html+='<p>Nothing!</p>';
}
```

Comment: It keeps spamming the div, how do I fix that

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out in JavaScript.

```
//Put the following if statment inside the done function
```

```
if (data != null) {
  document.getElementById('yourDivID').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p> Nothing! </p>');
}
```

This is how you would do it in jQuery.

```
//Put the following if statment inside the done function

if (data != null) {
  $('#yourDivID').append('<p> Nothing! </p>');
}
```